# SQL Report Server internal error

Tags: sql-server, dll, reporting-services

I'm running a report server on Windows Server 2008. After a recent update it would look like everything was fine in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager, but it can't actually be accessed. The error it gives if you visit the ReportServer URL is just "There was an internal error. See log"

```
ERROR: Error initializing configuration from the database: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. ---> <CrtImplementationDetails>.ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed to load.
 ---> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at _getFiberPtrId()
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
   at .cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionConfig..ctor()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager..ctor()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager..ctor(ConnectionTransactionType transactionType, IsolationLevel defaultIsolationLevel)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.Global.get_SharePointIntegratedFlagFromCatalog()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ServiceController.EnsureConfigurationFromDB()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ServiceAppDomainController.StartInternal(Object parentThread)
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!154!11/29/2016-09:09:05:: i INFO: Appdomain:2 WindowsService_0 started.
servicecontroller!WindowsService_0!154!11/29/2016-09:09:05:: e ERROR: Error initializing configuration from the database: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. ---> 
<CrtImplementationDetails>.ModuleLoadExceptionHandlerException: A nested exception occurred after the primary exception that caused the C++ module to fail to load.

--- Start of primary exception ---
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at _getFiberPtrId()
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
--- End of primary exception ---

--- Start of nested exception ---
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at CorBindToRuntimeEx(Char* , Char* , UInt32 , _GUID* , _GUID* , Void** )
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.DoCallBackInDefaultDomain(IntPtr function, Void* cookie)
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Cleanup(LanguageSupport* , Exception innerException)
--- End of nested exception ---

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionConfig..ctor()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager..ctor()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager..ctor(ConnectionTransactionType transactionType, IsolationLevel defaultIsolationLevel)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.Global.get_SharePointIntegratedFlagFromCatalog()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ServiceController.EnsureConfigurationFromDB()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ServiceAppDomain.StartService(IServiceAppDomainController appDomainController, Boolean firstStart)
```

I included more than you need maybe. The gist of it seems to be that it can't initialize because some memory is protected, although, in my recent experience that might just mean that some dll that's needed is missing/corrupted or something. I mention this because I removed the previous error by following [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1916.how-to-rebuild-the-report-server-performance-counters-ssrs.aspx).

Now it seems the same error is happening at _getFiberPtrId() but maybe I'm reading this error wrong. I was wondering if maybe I just need to reinstall another dll, but I haven't had any luck finding out which.

Anyone know?

Comment: What exactly was the update that was applied?

Comment: There were quite a few. They are all security updates for the .NET Framework 4.5. I did try uninstalling and reinstalling .NET 4.5 when the problem first began. I'm sorry, I think maybe the update was a red herring. I'm looking at the log and the ones I thought were responsible, optional Monthly quality rollups seem to have failed.